# Get row from table dimname in R

Tags: r

I have the following table:

```
> some.table
          Week
Person     17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
  Anna      0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  2  1  1  0  0  2
  Cloe      0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  2  0
  Heather   1  0  0  2  1  1  0  1  1  1  2  1  2  0
  Samantha  0  0  3  1  1  2  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
> str(some.table)
 'table' int [1:6, 1:14] 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ Person: chr [1:6] "Anna" "Cloe" "Heather" "Samantha"
  ..$ Week  : chr [1:14] "17" "18" "19" "20" ...
```

**How do I extract a row from that table by a person's name?**

E.g. for something like `some.table$Person["Cloe"]` I would like to get a vector `c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, notice the comma:

```
some.table["Cloe", ]
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
x <- with(mtcars, table(cyl, gear))
x
#    gear
# cyl  3  4  5
#   4  1  8  2
#   6  2  4  1
#   8 12  0  2

x[ "4", ]
# 3 4 5 
# 1 8 2
```

We can drop the column names using *unname*:

```
unname(x[ "4", ])
# [1] 1 8 2
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a `table` object, so either convert to `data.frame` and do the extraction.  The "Person", "Week" are the `names` attribute of the `dimnames`

```
subset(as.data.frame(some.table), Person == "Cloe")$Freq
```

---

Using a reproducible example with `mtcars`

```
data(mtcars)
some.table <- table(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$vs)
names(dimnames(some.table)) <- list("mpg", "vs")
subset(as.data.frame(some.table), mpg == 4)$Freq
#[1]  1 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out `some.table["Cloe", ]`